# Assign value to checkbox from database pull

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, checkbox

I'm trying to add a value to my checkbox. But It's not there when I'm trying to view it via inspect element. Here's how I do it.

Database select:

```
@amenities = AmenitiesAndFeatures.where(is_amenities: true).order("name ASC")

<% x=@amenities.size/2 %>
<% @amenities.each_with_index do |amenity,i|%>
  <% if i < x %>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="amenitiesAndFeaturesCheckbox" class="listing-check" value=<%@amenities[i].id%>>
    <%= @amenities[i].name %></p>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Any ideas? And is it right to name all checkboxes with the same name so in order to get all checked checkboxes . I just need to do this?

```
objects["amenitiesAndFeaturesCheckbox"].each do |amenitiesAndFeatures|
    listing_amenities_and_features.listing_id = listing_id
    listing_amenities_and_features.amenities_and_features_id = amenitiesAndFeatures
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<%=` at your `value` attribute, not `<%`:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... value=<%= @amenities[i].id %>>
```

Also, within your loop, there is no need to use `@amenities[i]`, and therefore no need to use `each_with_index`, since that's exactly what `amenity` is during each iteration of the loop. You can also get rid of the `x` variable and just use `take`:

```
<% @amenities.take(@amenities.size/2).each do |amenity| %>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="amenitiesAndFeaturesCheckbox" class="listing-check" value=<%= amenity.id %>>
    <%= amenity.name %>
  </p>
<%end%>
```